# Why is There a Deadlock Occurring Randomly in a Producer/Consumer Multithreaded C++ Program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, condition-variable, mutual-exclusion

In the code shown below, we were tasked with creating a consumer/producer program using multithreading and to find a way to prevent deadlock. This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <time.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>

#define MAX 100
#define MIN 0

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

class ProducerConsumer{

    public:

        // Creates a stack
        std::stack<int> stack_array;

        // Facilitates checking of values
        int producer_sum = 0;
        int consumer_sum = 0;

        // Generates random number
        int random_number_generator(){
            std::random_device rd;
            std::default_random_engine re{rd()};

            return re();
        }

        // Produces values and pushes them into the stack       
        void producer(){
            for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){

                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg(mtx);

                if (stack_array.size() == MAX){
                    std::cout << "Producer Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is waiting" << std::endl;
                    cv.wait(lg);
                }

                int rand_num = random_number_generator()%10+1;
                int rand_num_sleep = random_number_generator()%100+1;
                
                std::cout << "Current Stack Size -  " << stack_array.size() <<  " | Pushing: " << rand_num << "... " << "and sleeping for: " << rand_num_sleep << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

                producer_sum += rand_num;

                stack_array.push(rand_num); 

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand_num_sleep)); 
                
                cv.notify_all();
                lg.unlock();
            }
        }

        void consumer(){
            for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++) {

                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg(mtx);

                if (stack_array.size() == MIN){
                    std::cout << "Consumer Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is waiting" << std::endl;
                    cv.wait(lg);
                }

                int rand_num_sleep = random_number_generator()%100+1;
            
                std::cout << "Current Stack Size - " << stack_array.size() << " | Popping: " << stack_array.top() << "... " << "and sleeping for: " << rand_num_sleep << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

                consumer_sum += stack_array.top();

                stack_array.pop();  

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand_num_sleep));
                
                cv.notify_all();
                lg.unlock();
            }

        }
};

int main(){

    ProducerConsumer pc;

    std::thread producer_one (&ProducerConsumer::producer, &pc);
    std::thread consumer_one (&ProducerConsumer::consumer, &pc);
    std::thread producer_two (&ProducerConsumer::producer, &pc);
    std::thread consumer_two (&ProducerConsumer::consumer, &pc);

    producer_one.join();
    producer_two.join();
    consumer_one.join();
    consumer_two.join();

    std::cout << "Producer sum: " << pc.producer_sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Consumer sum: " << pc.consumer_sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stack size: " << pc.stack_array.size() << std::endl;
}
```

When trying to run the code, there are times where the code will encounter a deadlock due to what I assume is the program starting with the producer thread (which is understandable as I have not programmed a way to circumvent that). But sometimes, the code runs perfectly fine. Other times, the program gets a segmentation fault or encounters a deadlock mid-execution.

I assume my implementation of mutual exclusion is condition variables are correct. If not, can anyone explain what is wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that in addition to the issue explained in the answer, your code isnt really utilizing the threads to run in parallel. They all keep a lock on the same mutex for the whole duration of an iteration and only when the queue is full/empty they stop and a different thread continues. The workload, which you simulate with the sleep, should be done while not holding the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

condition variable wait always has to be in a loop because it can wake up and another thread has already taken the item, or it can wake up for no reason at all.

Of course the compiler won't tell you an error if there's no loop. I mean the variable is useless without the loop because it's not reliable.

Your producers use `notify_all` and you have two consumers, that means after one item is added you wake up both consumers (and both producers) and they both try to get the one item. Of course one of them is not going to have an item there - unless the other producer also produced an item (by chance) in the meantime.

Instead of:

```
            if (stack_array.size() == MAX){
                std::cout << "Producer Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is waiting" << std::endl;
                cv.wait(lg);
            }
```

you should simply change `if` to `while` - and the same in the consumers.

Note that looping is required even if you are careful to balance the number of notifies and consumes, because `wait` can return for no reason at all. On some operating systems, sometimes, `wait` isn't sure whether a notify happened or not, so it stops waiting anyway. This is called a "spurious wakeup". Then you check whether the queue is full and if it's still full you wait some more.

Comment: i'd always use the other overload which takes a predicate and encapsulates the loop. I find it a bit strange that the two are overloads with the same name but so different

Answer (score 2):

You need producers to wait until something has been consumed, and consumers to wait until something has been produced.
Right now, your threads just keep going whenever they wake up, regardless of what happened.
For instance, the consumer doesn't check wether there is anything on the stack when it wakes up, but the other consumer may have taken everything that was produced while it slept.
And then it tries to pop the stack, and program goes boom.

You also need to protect against "spurious wakeups".

Luckily, there's a `wait` overload that helps to handle both problems:

```
if (stack_array.size() == MAX){
    std::cout << "Producer Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is waiting" << std::endl;
    cv.wait(lg, [&stack_array]() { return stack_array.size() < MAX; });
}
```

and

```
if (stack_array.size() == MIN){
    std::cout << "Consumer Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " is waiting" << std::endl;
    cv.wait(lg, [&stack_array]() { return stack_array.size() > MIN; });
}
```

Comment: ...and at least as a rule of thumb, you normally want to use the overload of `wait` that takes a condition to wait for.